# Same screen keeps loading when trying to boot from USB

Tags: linux, boot, usb, bios, operating-systems

I installed Slax Linux onto my USB drive and used the Universal USB installer to make it bootable. I ran the bootinst.bat file and it said I was good to go. Then I changed the boot sequence in my BIOS to prioritize the USB. But when I rebooted, it just booted back to windows. Then, I pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> before boot and got a boot options menu where I could choose the USB, the SSD (Windows), or I could enter BIOS again. When I choose to boot from USB, it loads for about half a second before taking me to the exact same screen. I just want to boot Linux from USB, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that your [BIOS/UEFI settings are compatible with SLAX](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/usb-boot-problem.147210/). You may need to change legacy USB support, secure boot or other settings.
2. Be sure you're using the correct version: is you PC 32- or 64-bit?
3. Check that your USB flash drive is formatted so that the BIOS/UEFI can read it - FAT32 is most common.
4. Download the latest [Universal USB Installer (UUI)](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-2.0.0.4.exe), start with a clean, correctly formatted USB flash drive, and [follow the directions](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) for letting UUI install SLAX.